# Escape invalid XML with XSL, or otherwise create valid XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an output of a script that I can control the formatting of, but not perform functions on.

My end game is valid XML. Currently I am outputting the below .xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<NowPlaying>
   <ArtistName>Mickey</ArtistName>
   <SongName>Disney Mayhem</SongName>
   <AlbumCover>http://www.example.com/someplace/artwork name with @ character.jpg</AlbumCover>
</NowPlaying>
```

Some data contains unescaped `@`. Is it possible to transform this into valid XML using XSL? Or will the invalid input XML simply not parse?

Would it be better for my input data to come in as something simpler like [delimited string data](http://blog.lavgupta.com/2008/05/xsl-template-to-split-to-string.html)? Note each node only has the 3 value types as above.

None of my attempts have resulted in anything other than an invalid XML error.

Comment: You must input a well-formed XML. An XML that carries delimited values as its payload instead of marked up text, is just harder to process. It still must be well formed.

Comment: XSLT can only be used to process well-formed XML. If you are getting ill-formed XML you should not attempt to repair it, you should fix the process that creates it.

Comment: Ok so not possible. Is there perhaps another way? Maybe I write the data as CSV, and use php to encode before xsl forms valid XML? I'll reiterate... The data is as is (unescaped), and I can't perform functions, just modify the format of the export.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up using...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<NowPlaying>
   <ArtistName><![CDATA[Mickey]]></ArtistName>
   <SongName><![CDATA[Disney Mayhem]]></SongName>
   <AlbumCover><![CDATA[http://www.example.com/someplace/artwork name with @ character.jpg]]></AlbumCover>
</NowPlaying>
```

While I'm not technically creating valid XML with XSL, I was able to achieve my objective of creating valid XML with my unescaped data. Unfortunately, for my end use (a third party parser) it was only useful for handling `&` as `@` still breaks the URL links.

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp) is some info on CDATA

Answer (score 0):

The usual work flow with XSLT is parsing an XML input document with an XML parser into a tree of nodes the XSLT operates on and generates a result tree which can be serialized as XML or HTML or plain text. There are some tool chains which allow you to plug in an HTML parser in the first step to parse HTML into a tree of nodes. Your example is neither well-formed XML nor HTML. So in general you will need to find a way to fix your input that does neither use an XML parser nor XSLT, once you have well-formed XML you can then use XSLT.

Comment: OK thanks... See my comment above. Is there perhaps some workaround with a PHP file on the server?

Comment: If you use PHP to construct your input then I am sure it has APIs that help creating well-formed XML, like http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php or http://php.net/manual/en/book.xmlwriter.php.